# How to get status code in jwt token based error msg using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express-jwt, nodejs-server

I implemented JWT token authentication using node.js and MongoDB. It's working fine. Throwing error messages is also working fine (token invalid, JWT expired, JWT must be provided). But how do I get the appropriate HTTP status code in the error message automatically?

```js
// jwt.js

function Verify_Token(accessToken) {
    jwt.verify(accessToken, config.get("jwtprivatekey"), function (err) {
        value = err

    });
    return value

}
```

Comment: Where do you want the error status code to come from? I'll expect an error code coming from a API call but not from a jot verification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jwt.verify wont return any numeric status code in case of error.  As per the documentation of jsonwebtoken npm module, we can clearly see that it just return the below fields when it throws error.

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {
  /*
     err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
     }
  */
  }
});
```

If you have to return some status code from your nodejs web server, you have to embedd the status code in http response along with the error message from jwt. Something like below.

```
jwt.verify(token, 'shhhhh', function(err, decoded) {
  if (err) {

     err = {
        name: 'TokenExpiredError',
        message: 'jwt expired',
        expiredAt: 1408621000
     }
     return res.status(401).send(err)
  }
});
```

Comment: supposs how to throw different error on .(token invalid, JWT expired, JWT must be provided)

Comment: @smith hari, You can modify the error object returned from jwt.verify.